# How does ssh or any other service work without pam?

Tags: ssh, login, pam

I do not understand how ssh or any other service can work without pam.
pam defines all the rules, if I understand correctly, calls other modules to set resources or restrictions etc.

Can someone explain how does SSH behave, if we set `UsePam=No`.
Which modules takes care of authentication, session creation etc.?

Comment: `sshd` is already capable of authenticating users. Using PAM just means that the configuration can be centralized and/or extended.

Comment: okay..so can we say that su in linux (Eg: RHEL) can't work without pam?

Comment: What are you asking here? It's been pointed out that sshd can authenticate without pam. Certainly one could have su also have its own authentication outside of pam. Pam is a convenience, not a mandate to use.

Comment: There was a time before PAM. What do you think how `sshd` and `su` worked back then?

Comment: There are non-Linux Unix systems without PAM. The OpenBSD system does not use PAM and OpenSSH is developed (mainly) by OpenBSD developers.

Comment: @HaukeLaging and others (but I can only tag one): I think they wrote the question exactly because they don't know the answer to it. If you have an answer, write it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set `UsePam no`, then `sshd` itself will do the job of the PAM modules, as best as it can.

Since `sshd` is running as root, it can use `getspnam(3)` function to get the user's password hash and other information from `/etc/shadow` (or from NIS, LDAP or any other storage location supported by the C library of the system), select the password hashing algorithm by looking at the beginning of the hash, then hash the password entered by the user with the salt from the `getspnam(3)` result using `crypt(3)`. The result is then compared to the complete password hash retrieved by `getspnam(3)`. If they match, the password authentication is successful.

Account verification step is again pretty simple: the password expiration information is included in the `getspnam(3)` results, and another check is made that the user's shell exists and is listed in `/etc/shells`.

Session creation includes a number of steps whose details depend on the type of Linux or Unix the service is running on. But typically, for a shell session, the `sshd` child process handling this specific connection would record the session information to the `utmp` and `wtmp` files, set up a pseudo-TTY, then `fork()` another child process that would take on the user's UID and group memberships, switch to the user's home directory and call `setsid()` to become a session leader. This process would then `exec()` the user's shell.

When the shell dies, the `sshd` child process holding the master end of the pseudo-TTY would then perform any necessary clean-up actions, like recording the end of session in the `wtmp` file.

This is roughly how a Unix session was handled before PAM was invented.

Comment: Great answer mate, thank you.